# Keeping debug strings out of build in C#

Tags: c#, logging, c-preprocessor

When writing code, I often place debug messages in the code. The debug messages are handled by a logger class, which outputs the messages to file in debug mode and discards them in release modes.

It looks a little something like this:

```
class Logger : IDisposable
{
    private StreamWriter m_Logger = null;

    public void Start(string logFile)
    {
        m_Logger = new StreamWriter(logFile);
        m_Logger.AutoFlush = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (m_Logger != null) m_Logger.Dispose();
    }

    public void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        if (m_Logger != null) m_Logger.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

An instance is created at startup, and is accessible from the `Program` class. I then check for debug like this:

```
#if DEBUG
Program.Log.Start("app.log");
#endif
```

This works great, in that it dumps debug info when in debug mode, and doesn't in release mode. However, if I run the release executable through a utility such as `strings`, I can still see the debug strings. I'd prefer to keep them out of the release build entirely, to help prevent reverse engineering.

The only solution I've found so far is to wrap all debug messages in preprocessor conditionals:

```
// < some code here >
#if DEBUG
Program.Log.WriteLine("Some debug message.");
#endif
// < more code here >
```

This is pretty tedious and ugly. My first thought was to use some sort of preprocessor macro, but C# doesn't support them. Is there a more elegant solution than the one I'm using right now?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for, but maybe you could mark the methods in the logger with [a conditional DEBUG attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664622%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)?

Comment: You really need to check out log4net.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs I've used log4net before, but this project is way too small to warrant the external library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To avoid using #if-#endif on each WriteLine call, try using [ConditionalAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) on the logger method itself:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public void WriteLine(string message)
{
    if (m_Logger != null) m_Logger.WriteLine(message);
}
```

This will be excluded from MSIL in case of a Release build.

> Applying ConditionalAttribute to a method indicates to compilers that
>   a call to the method should not be compiled into Microsoft
>   intermediate language (MSIL) unless the conditional compilation symbol
>   that is associated with ConditionalAttribute is defined. Applying
>   ConditionalAttribute to an attribute indicates that the attribute
>   should not be emitted to metadata unless the conditional compilation
>   symbol is defined

Comment: This will cause all of the calls to WriteLine to fail unless they are also excluded won't they?

Comment: Why to fail? Just won't be executed in a Release build, as they will be  missing from the code.

Comment: It removes the target method and causes the compiler to essentially ignore all of the *calls*, removing them from the IL entirely. This works perfectly! :)

Comment: @Polynomial: Glad to hear that. I've used it once for the same reason :)

Comment: @JasonCoyne - The `WriteLine` calls are all surrounded by an `#if DEBUG` directive.

Comment: @Lieven No, they're not. The `Conditional` attribute just omits all calls to the target method from the IL, so (as far as anyone reading the IL is concerned) the method doesn't exist and is never called.

Comment: @Polynomial - Just to get this straight: you **don't** need to surround all calls with the directive, just add the conditional to the method signature and the compiler will throw away all calls to WriteLine? That would be impressive.

Comment: @Lieven Yup, that's the case. Just verified with ildasm - no calls, no method code. Impressive indeed!

Answer (score 0):

1) Put the #ifdef inside the body of the the log method, so that you dont have to put defines around every log message

2) If you are trying to prevent reverse engineering, obfuscate the code,which would encrypt the strings, but this is not a failsafe.

3) You could use something like PostSharp to actively delete the code from the MSIL after the fact http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/logging